# Android App Bundle Signed in using wrong key. My certificate with fingerprint does not match what is expected

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, key, digital-signature

I'm trying to publish my flutter app on the Play Store but am encountering this error:
"Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again. Your App Bundle is expected to be signed with the certificate with fingerprint:
but the certificate used to sign the App Bundle you uploaded has fingerprint:"

[[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdrfD.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSp93.png)

I requested to reset the upload key, got it approved, and am still encountering the same error. I'm pretty sure my StorePassword, keyPassword, keyAlias and storeFile in my key.properties file is correct.
One thing I should note is that I have there have been previous releases of my app. But I have reset my key, so I'm not sure why there is an error.

Here's what I have tried:

- I followed the instructions in https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android, tried ./gradlew clean, flutter clean, flutter build appbundle.
- I have reset my upload key before, exported created certificate to PEM format.
- I am sure I am on the correct app in Google Play. I have tried flutter build appbundle --release
- I made sure I have the key.properties file, upload-keystore.jks file, and everything as stated in the docs in my build.gradle file
- I was able to create the app-release.aab file using the flutter build appbundle --release command using my password in key.properties file. The part that I am stuck on is why Play expected my app to be signed with the different certificate.
- I tried uploading an APK but got the same error.

Thanks